# calling the fuction from another file - arguments issue

Tags: python, function, tweepy

I'm streaming Twitter's APIs with tweepy in python. I have the code like this:

```
import tweepy
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token_key = ''
access_token_secret = ''

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        json_data = json.loads(data)

        print (data.text)
```

I'd like to call this function in another file. Right now I have this:

```
from tweetsstreaming import StdOutListener

listener = StdOutListener()
listener.on_data()
```

and I'm stuck at this, I have no idea how to pass the argument `data` to my `listener.on_data()`. I really spent a lot of time looking for the answer but can't find anything to resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [streaming example](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/examples/streaming.py). You need to register your listener like this:

```
listener = StdOutListener()
stream = Stream(auth, listener)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the following in the secondary file to call out the class and access Twitter API through oAuth:

```
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, StdOutListener())

# this part is optional if you need to add filters
stream.filter(track=['twitter'])
```